# Unix read -p command causes bash error, how do I fix it?

Tags: bash, prompt

I'm trying to prompt the user for a comment

```
function comment {
  if [ ! $1 ]
  then
   read -p "enter checkin comment &lt; " COMMENT;     
  else
   export COMMENT="$1"
  fi 

  if [ ! $COMMENT ]
  then
    echo 'no comment!'
  else
    echo "$COMMENT";
  fi  
}
```

**UPDATED**
This happens when I enter more than one word into the prompt, if I enter "update" for example I dont get an error message... but if I enter more than one word

```
enter checkin comment >> sun mars venus
```

then I get the error (always on the second word)

```
-bash: [: mars: binary operator expected
```

Comment: Are those lines the whole thing? No error here.

Comment: No error here too.

Comment: The error is in another line which you haven't shown. Post the whole script.

Comment: What version of bash do you have? I've confirmed it works as written with double quotes on Cygwin's bash (Win7), bash (CentOS 5), and BusyBox (TomatoUSB).

Comment: Ive updated my post hopefully theres enough info there now to answer (CentOS 5/Bash)

Comment: @codeninja You should accept Gilles' answer - and I can then remove mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if [ ! $COMMENT ]
```

I think you meant to check whether `$COMMENT` is non-empty, but that's not what this command does. An unquoted variable substitution undergoes filename generation (globbing) and word splitting. Here, you're entering several words in your comment (`sun mars venus`) so the `[` command sees `! sun mars venus` (4 arguments) which is not valid syntax. Always put double quotes around variable substitutions:

```
if [ ! "$COMMENT" ]
```

In this particular case, this tests whether `$COMMENT` is non-empty. This is a shortcut because there are only two shell words inside the brackets. In the general case, the way to test whether a string is non-empty is to use the `-n` operator, and the `-z` operator tests whether the string is empty.

```
if [ -z "$COMMENT" ]
```

In ksh/bash/zsh, you can use the `[[ … ]]` construct instead of the `[ … ]` command. The single brackets are an ordinary command bound by the usual shell syntax rules, whereas the double brackets are a special shell syntax with its own rules. There is no word splitting inside double brackets, so you can write

```
if [[ -z $COMMENT ]]
```

Double quotes wouldn't hurt though.

The same goes for `if [ ! $1 ]` which should be `if [ -z "$1" ]` or `if [[ -z $1 ]]`.

There's an additional oddity that you export the `COMMENT` variable to the environment when the comment is passed as an argument to the function but not when you read it with the `read` built-in. Unless you need to pass `COMMENT` to an external program, drop the word `export`.

Answer (score 1):

Bash is interpreting the`[` as the `test` command (which requires spaces around the argument). See [Greg's Wiki on tests & conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29)...

Comment: The `[` is inside a quoted string, so how can it be interpreted as the `test` command?

Comment: Based on the code provided, and the error message, that is the only conclusion I can draw.

Comment: Ive updated my post hopefully theres enough info there now to answer

Comment: You need to use quotes in your `test` - otherwise the words are split and bash sees more than one argument for `test` See: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes